# How to test within the same module?

Tags: java, junit5, java-module

In this project I have a modular setup. There is a parent with two modules in it.

Here's a snippet from the parent-pom.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
</modules>
```

Both modules have a module-info.java. Here is the module-info.java for moduleB:

```
module moduleB {
    requires spring.web;
    requires static lombok;
    requires java.validation;
    requires swagger.annotations;
    requires slf4j.api;
    exports com.example.service
}
```

Within moduleB there is the main folder and the test folder, like any regular java project. Within the test-folder there is a JUnit5 test, which is trying to test a service within the same package, but in the src-folder.

While trying to attempt this, I get the following error-message:

```
module moduleB does not "opens com.example.service" to unnamed module @67205a84
```

As I understand, all of the dependencies which are not part of the module will be packaged in an 'unnamed' module. In this case module @67205a84. Things I expect to be in this module are stuff like Mockito, which I only use for testing. Please correct me if I'm wrong about this assumption.

When I open up my moduleB (by adding the word 'open' before the moduledecleration), the test runs smoothly. But obviously this is not what I want.

So my question really is: can I open up to the unnamed module so that my tests can run, but my module stays closed for anything other than the test?

Here's a simplified overview of the directory structure.

```
- parent
  |
  -> - pom.xml
     - moduleA
     - moduleB
       |
       -> - pom.xml
          - src
            |
            -> - main
                 |
                 -> - java
                      |
                      -> - module.info
                         - com.example.service
                           |
                           -> - ModuleBService.java
               - test
                 | 
                 -> - java
                      | 
                      -> - com.example
                           |
                           -> - Application.java
                         - com.example.service
                           | 
                           -> - ModuleBServiceTest.java
```

As it turns out, the location of the Application.class is relevant. The module I am trying to test does not have a class annotated with @SpringbootApplication, because it's just a library. To test it's functionality, I have to start a SpringbootApplication in test. When the Application.java is in the same package as the ModuleBServiceTest.java, all is well. When I move it out in another package the error-message from above occurs. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to configure the surefire plugin to open the module to the unnamed modules in the POM of your `moduleB`

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>
          <!-- Allow access to the tests during test time -->
          --add-opens moduleB/com.example.service=ALL-UNNAMED
          <!-- Add export to test-util classes to moduleC if it wants to reuse these -->
          --add-exports moduleB/com.example.service.test.util=moduleC
          <!-- Prevent any illegal access to modules -->
          --illegal-access=deny
        </argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I've also added a sample where you can explicitly export some test utility classes to a further module in case it wants to access these

> As it turns out, the location of the Application.class is relevant. The module I am trying to test does not have a class annotated with @SpringbootApplication, because it's just a library. To test it's functionality, I have to start a SpringbootApplication in test. When the Application.java is in the same package as the ModuleBServiceTest.java, all is well. When I move it out in another package the error-message from above occurs. Why is that?

AFAIK Spring Boot will scan its package and any sub-packages for components, services and the like and will add these automatically to its configuration. If the application is not directly in an ancestor path it might not be able to find your test class, though the information given is a bit limited to be honest.